# Find(1): test 'A' pass but test 'A -o B' fails

Tags: find

This function doesn't print out anything;

```bash
skyrimse_testroot() {
    local directory="$1"
    find "$directory" \
        \( -type f -ipath "${directory}/data/scripts/*.pex"        \) -o \
        \( -type d -ipath "${directory}/data/meshes"               \) \
        -print -quit
}
```

But this one does (I removed the second test group);

```bash
skyrimse_testroot() {
    local directory="$1"
    find "$directory" \
        \( -type f -ipath "${directory}/data/scripts/*.pex"        \)  \
        -print -quit
}
```

`$1` is an absolute path, so is the starting point and the `-ipath` arguments.

Based on my humble knowledge of boolean logic, chaining more OR clauses to a positive expression should not make that expression evaluate negatively. Either `find` is broken or I got something wrong, and I suspect one option more than the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say broken but the precedence in `find` tests can be very surprising especially the way actions are involved.

From https://manpages.debian.org/stable/findutils/find.1.en.html

> NON-BUGS
>
> Operator precedence surprises
>
> The command `find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print` will never print
> *afile* because this is actually equivalent to `find . -name afile -o \( -name bfile -a -print \)`. Remember that the precedence of `-a` is higher than that of `-o` and when there is no operator specified between tests,
> `-a` is assumed.

So in your example your current parentheses are not necessary because 'and' has higher precedence but you must add them around all tests.

```
find "$directory" \
        '(' \
            -type f -ipath "${directory}/data/scripts/*.pex" \
            -o \
            -type d -ipath "${directory}/data/meshes" \
        ')' \
        -print -quit
```